# XML-RPC - cannot marshal recursive dictionaries

Tags: python, recursion, dictionary, marshalling, xml-rpc

I have a simple example to send a dictionary through xml-rpc:

```
 class CTest(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.node1 = {'data':'zek', 'parent':{},  'children':[]}
        self.node2 = {'data':'bill', 'parent':{}, 'children':[]}
        self.node1['children'].append(self.node2)
        self.node2['parent'] = self.node1

    def getNode(self):
        return self.node1
```

I have two dictionaries: node2 is the children of node1, and in the same time node2 has the reference of node1 as parent variable.
So it is a recursive dictionary. When I try to send node1 through XML-RPC, I got this exception:

```
#Command to execute xml-rpc dump method for serialization
test = CTest()
xmlrpclib.dumps((test,), 'Node Object')
#Exception
raise TypeError, "cannot marshal recursive dictionaries"
```

Is it possible to send node1 through XML-RPC (without changing dictionary structure)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Serialize and deserialize 'test' yourself by using the 'pickle' module of Python.

```
cPickle.dumps(test)
```

is working. On the other side of the wire you use

```
cPickle.loads(received_test_pickle)
```

It might be necessary to base-64 encode/decode the pickle before/after the XMLRPC call.

But also look into PyRo

http://pyro.sourceforge.net/

Comment: thanks. It works perfect with cPickle. But it needs to be language independent.
So when I pickle the dictionary on one peer, I also need to use python in other peer to unpickle it.
Because I am sending dictionary in xml-format, Normally it is possible to use another programming language in another peer(C,C++,java)
That is why I can not use pickle.
Pyro has its own network communication code, and it doesn't use XML-RPC. I need to use XML-RPC.
So do you know any other method to send this dictionary through XML-RPC without pickle?